# Regex for URL with query string

Tags: regex, url, query-string

I'm trying to create a regular expression to use as a rule in fiddler. I'm not very good at regular expressions.

This regular expression:

```
http://myServer:28020/MyService/ItemWebService.json?([a-zA-Z]+)
```

Matches the URL below:

```
http://myServer:28020/MyService/ItemWebService.json?action=keywordSearch&username=StockOnHandPortlet&sessionId=2H7Rr9kCWPgIZfrxQiDHKp0&keywords=blue&itemStatus=A
```

So far so good. But why when I try this regular expression:

```
http://myServer:28020/MyService/ItemWebService.json?action=keywordSearch([a-zA-Z]+)
```

It does not match the above URL. Why would that be?

Comment: tried that. It doesn't work either. Does the & need to be escaped?

Comment: What do you need to match? The whole URL? Only the query string? Or the part before the query string? Mind that `.` and `?` must be escaped outside of character class.

Comment: the whole url. Before fiddler intercepts the http requests it wants to check that a url matches the pattern specified.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In a regular expression, you need to escape `.` and `?` outside of character class.

So, this is enough to match the URL itself:

```
http://myServer:28020/MyService/ItemWebService\.json
```

URL with query string can be matched with

```
http://myServer:28020/MyService/ItemWebService\.json\??(?:&?[^=&]*=[^=&]*)*
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lP9uL0/2)

**Explanation**:

- `http://myServer:28020/MyService/ItemWebService\.json` - matches the base URL where we need to escape `.` to match it literally
- `\??` - matches 0 or 1 (due to `?` quantifier) literal `?`
- `(?:&?[^=&]*=[^=&]*)*` - matches 0 or more (due to `*`) sequences of `&?[^=&]*=[^=&]*`:

  - `&?` - 0 or 1 `&` (no need escaping)
  - `[^=&]*` - 0 or more characters other than `=` and `&`
  - `=` - n equals sign
  - `[^=&]*` - 0 or more characters other than `=` and `&`

If you want to match a URL that has the first query parameter=value set to `action=keywordSearch`, you can use the [following regex](https://regex101.com/r/lP9uL0/3):

```
http://myServer:28020/MyService/ItemWebService\.json\?action=keywordSearch(?:&?[^=&]*=[^=&]*)*
```

Comment: thanks. This worked for me. I understand your explanation as well about escaping. Can you elaborate on the bit inside the brackets for us beginners.

Comment: thanks. Actually sorry to bother but could you modify you answer to include the action=keywordSearch. I was always able to match the url without the action part but it was when i added the action part that i couldn't get the regex right.

Comment: Ok, I added that version.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
(\?|\&)([^=]+)\=([^&]+)
```

With g option (global)

```
http://myServer:28020/MyService/ItemWebService.json(\?|\&)([^=]+)\=([^&]+)
```

Comment: Sorry but fiddler also said that the url does not match the pattern

Comment: Add your URL in front of it

Comment: just using `([^=]+)\=([^&]+)` matching `asd` and `asd=asd` and also `asd=`.... how do I use this with pattern attribute to match only the query string?